# Log4j1.x LoggingEnvent : can't get the Object

Tags: java, sockets, serialization, log4j, instanceof

I use Log4j1.x for sending by Socket (SocketAppender in AsyncAppender) some  loggingEvent.

I send a personnal object Serializable in the LoggingEvent message.

In the Chainsaw (example of server wide), I would like to recover my personnal object.

- I can show the class name (event.getMessage().toString())
- I can get the throwable
- My personnal object is in a library, the same in the both projects.

My problem : I can't instance the message.

the error :

```
Exception in thread "Thread-5" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.my.MyPersonnalObject
    at org.apache.log4j.chainsaw.LoggingReceiver$Slurper.run(LoggingReceiver.java:80)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

How can I rescure my Object ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simply way.

Override the toString of MyPersonnalObject to return an JSON value :

```
@Override
public String toString()
{
    String str = "";
    try
    {
        str = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(this);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e)
    {
        StringWriter errors = new StringWriter();
        e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(errors));
        str = "ERROR JSON" + errors.toString();
    }
    return str;
}
```

Then, on the other side, use :

```
public static MyPersonnalObject rescure(String jsonStr)
{
    MyPersonnalObject b = null;

    try
    {
        JsonParser jsonParser = jsonFactory.createParser(jsonStr);
        b = objectMapper.readValue(jsonParser, MyPersonnalObject.class);

    } catch (JsonParseException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return b;
}
```